# Adding Watch Variable crashes xcode

Tags: xcode

I am trying to add watch on my variable in the debug area. But whenever I click on "Add Expression..." its crashes my xcode. Is there another way to add watch. I am using xcode 4.3.3

Comment: Did you try adding the expression when you are in the debug session or when you are just not debugging anything. It depends on **when** you are adding the expression I guess. I got the crash when I tried to **add expression** when I was not actually in the debug session. Once in, I was able to add the watch/expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your debugger:

1) Press Cmd + Shift + ,

2) Choose "Test" on right panel

3) Click on Debugger and choose a LLDB, if current a GDB, otherwise at vice versa